# VS Code Extension, how to programme a refresh of PlantUML preview

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, vscode-extensions, plantuml

How can I force PlantUML to refresh its preview, using code?

**Longer Explanation**

I have 2 editors open
Editor 1 contains a yml file.
Editor 2 contains a plantuml .wsd file
and a 3rd pane is showing the plantuml preview. (which is technically not an editor)

When I modify the yml file, it modifies a json model, and rewrites the .wsd file, and thus I get a new state diagram showing me the structure of my yml file in graph format.

The content of wsd is updating correctly when the yml changes. V1 created a new file each time, it saved fine I could see the content change, but the preview never updated.

Settings->PlantUML auto update is ticked.

In order to trigger the refresh I had to select the editor, and either modify or save.

So I re-wrote the code to select the editor 2 wsd contents, replace it in the existing file, and then save that file.  Still the preview does not update.

I have also tried to fire the vscode command plantuml.preview, which is what the plantuml extension itself fires to display the preview, it fires and returns, but does not update the preview.

I have vscode.window.visibleTextEditors[ii], from which I can select the right editor, but I cannot find anything to set the focus. I've tried setting selections, and saving but still no refresh.

I am now trying to find the right vs code way to set the focus on the right editor and save it, then switch back to the left editor, mimicking pressing CMD-2, CMD-S, CMD-1, or manually selecting the editor and saving, which is the only way to update the preview.

I cannot find anything on how to set the editor focus, so perhaps I am going down the wrong path. Can anyone suggest how this could be done?

[image: My 2 Editors and a Preview Panel]

Comment: As that preview needs to monitor changes from several files, you need a project model defined in the background to trigger preview updates, and also file/editor update events to trigger model updates. Merely tracking focus change won’t help much.

Comment: @LexLi As far as I know, the preview is only monitoring the right hand editor, that is the wsd file for generating the diagram. Are you saying that plantuml is also looking elsewhere?  Can you define what you mean by "project model"? Do you mean my json model which is matching the yml changes?  If so, I am already triggering events when the scenario.yml file changes and my model updates, and then updates the code in the generated.wsd file. The only bit that doesn't update is the diagram, how do I trigger that to update?

Comment: So do you rely on another extension (like [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jebbs.plantuml)) to render the preview? If so you might need to call its own command (like `plantuml.preview`) to force an update when needed.

Comment: Yes, exactly that extension and I tried calling         vscode.commands.executeCommand('plantuml.preview')
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Refreshed plantuml");
        });  and I get the log, but no update in the preview window.

Comment: Can you try to debug the PlantUML extension in this case? https://github.com/qjebbs/vscode-plantuml Once the logic behind `plantuml.preview` is clear, I think you are not too far from the answer.